# How have a generic conversion from 32/24bit From Bytes To 16bit To bytes

Tags: c#, audio, byte, wav, bit

Have been searching the solution for two days.
I want to convert my wave 32 or 24 bits to a 16bit.

This my code after reading few stackoverflow topics):

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String("-- Wav String encoded --") (32 or 24 bits)
int  conv =  Convert.ToInt16(data);
byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(conv);
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
   Array.Reverse(intBytes);
 byte[] result = intBytes;
```

but when i writeAllbyte my result, nothing to hear...

Comment: That's because you converted the array object to one `short` and right after that to `int`. How do you want to convert if the samples are so big that an `int16` can't hold the data? Do you want to cut off the least significant bits? Then you just need to throws those bytes away in your input `data`. No need to `Convert`.

Comment: Thanks you for your anwsear. I don't have experience with bits and bytes... I read you and search in internet how to remove the LSB but nothing much about it... And about you said, are you telling me that my Convert.toInt16 is no needed here? But how to convert 32b to 16 then?

Comment: If you want to convert 32 bit to 16 bit, you have to make a tradeoff. For sound data it is probably reasonable to loose some precision. The precision is stored in the least significant bits. So we can throw them away (assuming that there is still some data in the other bits and that there is no other encoding like differential etc.) So to convert 32 to 16 bit, take 2 bytes, skip 2 bytes until you're at the end of the array. For 24 to 16 bit take 2 bytes, skip 1 byte. Either construct a new array with this procedure or use a list to remove elements (more convenient, but less efficient).

Comment: Mhh I see `           byte[] newby = {};
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i+= 2)
            {
                newby[i] = data[i];
            }` . Have i to use >> 8 or something else? I have the out of bounds error

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that cuts the least significant bits:

```
byte[] data = ...
var skipBytes = 0;
byte[] data16bit;
int samples;
if( /* data was 32 bit */ ) {
    skipBytes = 2;
    samples = data.Length / 4;
} else if( /* data was 24 bit */ ) {
    skipBytes = 1;
    samples = data.Length / 3;
}
data16bit = new byte[samples * 2];
int writeIndex = 0;
int readIndex = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < samples; ++i) {
    readIndex += skipBytes; //skip the least significant bytes
    //read the two most significant bytes
    data16bit[writeIndex++] = data[readIndex++];
    data16bit[writeIndex++] = data[readIndex++];
}
```

This assumes a little endian byte order (least significant byte is the first byte, usual for WAV RIFF). If you have big endian, you have to put the `readIndex += ...` after the two read lines.

You could implement your own conversion iterator for this task like so:

```
IEnumerable<byte> ConvertTo16Bit(byte[] data, int skipBytes)
{
    int bytesToRead = 0;
    int bytesToSkip = skipBytes;
    int readIndex = 0;
    while (readIndex < data.Length)
    {
        if (bytesToSkip > 0)
        {
            readIndex += bytesToSkip;
            bytesToSkip = 0;
            bytesToRead = 2;
            continue;
        }
        if (bytesToRead == 0)
        {
            bytesToSkip = skipBytes;
            continue;
        }
        yield return data[readIndex++];
        bytesToRead--;
    }
}
```

This way you don't have to create a new array if there is no need for it. And you could simply convert the data array to a new 16 bit array with the `IEnumerable<T>` extension methods:

```
var data16bit = ConvertTo16Bit(data, 1).ToArray();
```

Or if you don't need the array, you can iterate the data skipping the least significant bytes:

```
foreach (var b in ConvertTo16Bit(data, 1))
{
    Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your  help. I understand thanks to your explanation & code. There's just one problem, the new data written isn't playing sound :-( ... so...

Comment: Hey, I figured out when i put `skipBytes = 0` the data written is playing  with lower length (of music). The size of file is lower thats ok but the quality seems the same... with less sound

Comment: Have you changed the wave header to 16 bit?

Comment: If you are talking about your code Yes. But if it's another things to do so No. SO i need to change wave header then?

Comment: There are few pages with waves Header but they begin with nothing to create a wave file. My example is a bit more complicated. Begin with a byte array -> change header -> change bits -> byte array...

Comment: So your `data` array includes the header? Then this won't work. You have to split the header from the sample data. You can then modify the sample data with the above method. Then change the bits/sample value in the header (offset 34 of the fmt-part) and put it together again.

Comment: mmmh so the method should not work with the header, that's why. I am currently working with memoryStream/ Binary Read/Write for the header things. i think it will work. I will let you know in few hours (and mark resolved. Thanks

Comment: Hey, i extracted wave Header, change but and sample. Extracted data sound, with your stuff but i when play sound, The sound is very SLOW, like in sow motion. I have to adapt sound frequency also? or something else?

Comment: Yes, you have to adapt the byte rate (offset 28).